# Is there a way of hiding navigation bar and status bar in android 11?

Tags: navigation, hide, status

Is there any way to hide the navigation bar and status/navigation bar in android 11?

Before android 11 this would do the trick:
`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)`;

Now I can only make them transparent like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

Is there any way of making them disappear now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().hide(
                android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
                        | android.view.WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes